# Discerning GoDaddy SSL Certificate Types

Tags: tomcat, ssl-certificate, godaddy

I'm following these instructions for installing a GoDaddy Certificate in Apache Tomcat:

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5239/generating-a-csr-and-installing-an-ssl-certificate-in-tomcat-4x5x6x?locale=en

However, in the steps a root certificate, intermediate certificate, and certificate are referenced. How can I tell which file is which?

These are the names of the three files that I received in the download. I've tried opening each one in windows by simply double clicking too, but I see no reference to their type.

gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt

gdig2.crt

2b9918dccf2f1d.crt

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- `gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt`: Go Daddy Certificate Bundles - G2 With Cross to G1, includes Root
- `gdig2.crt`: Go Daddy Secure Server Certificate (Intermediate Certificate) - G2
- `2b9918dccf2f1d.crt`: Your certificate

Source: https://certs.godaddy.com/anonymous/repository.pki

Comment: I only got `gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt` and my certificate (`2b99xxxxxxx.crt`). No `gdig2.crt`!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `openssl`'s [`x509`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/x509) subcommand:

```
openssl x509 -subject -issuer -noout -in cert.pem
```

and check the output. Should be self explanatory.

An example:

```
$ openssl x509 -noout -issuer -subject -in gd-class2-root.crt
issuer= /C=US/O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc./OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
subject= /C=US/O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc./OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority

$ openssl x509 -noout -issuer -subject -in gd_intermediate.crt
issuer= /C=US/O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc./OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
subject= /C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository/CN=Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority/serialNumber=07969287
```

You can also verify the chain of trust:

```
$ openssl verify -CAfile gd-class2-root.crt gd_intermediate.crt
gd_intermediate.crt: OK
```

Comment: Where did you get the pem file from?  We only got crt and key files.

Comment: https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/pem-ssl-creation.htm